# Can I support all these sensors? Will I have enough pins?

Tags: arduino-mega, pins, components

So i'm new to arduino and i'm working on a project that will require 3 modules/sensors.
I wanted to know, can all of the following modules work with the arduino mega 2560 that comes with [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32756200704.html?spm=a2g0o.detail.1000013.12.711673f1ncqoRr&gps-id=pcDetailBottomMoreThisSeller&scm=1007.13339.169870.0&scm_id=1007.13339.169870.0&scm-url=1007.13339.169870.0&pvid=f8448ca9-d64e-4e65-ab67-9449f3d31926&_t=gps-id:pcDetailBottomMoreThisSeller,scm-url:1007.13339.169870.0,pvid:f8448ca9-d64e-4e65-ab67-9449f3d31926,tpp_buckets:668%230%23131923%230_668%230%23131923%230_668%23888%233325%2318_668%23888%233325%2318_668%232846%238111%231996_668%235811%2327175%2321_668%232717%237558%23144_668%231000022185%231000066058%230_668%233468%2315612%23337_668%232846%238111%231996_668%235811%2327175%2321_668%232717%237558%23144_668%233164%239976%23596_668%233468%2315612%23337)
touch display?

The other modules (apart from the touch display) would be:

- [Fingerprint scanner](https://he.aliexpress.com/item/1005001692576941.html?spm=a2g0o.detail.1000060.2.1d0f7d47W6D9VB&gps-id=pcDetailBottomMoreThisSeller&scm=1007.13339.169870.0&scm_id=1007.13339.169870.0&scm-url=1007.13339.169870.0&pvid=e6840541-0a73-4a77-af30-11823a618765&_t=gps-id:pcDetailBottomMoreThisSeller,scm-url:1007.13339.169870.0,pvid:e6840541-0a73-4a77-af30-11823a618765,tpp_buckets:668%230%23131923%230_668%230%23131923%230_668%23888%233325%2318_668%23888%233325%2318_668%232846%238111%231996_668%235811%2327175%2321_668%232717%237558%23144_668%231000022185%231000066058%230_668%233468%2315612%23365_668%232846%238111%231996_668%235811%2327175%2321_668%232717%237558%23144_668%233164%239976%23596_668%233468%2315612%23365)
- [9g servo](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002056653701.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.5cb93734JK6wGL&algo_pvid=aebdfac6-36b8-4f2d-9b74-4a6fad059f04&algo_exp_id=aebdfac6-36b8-4f2d-9b74-4a6fad059f04-3)

If its not possible, please tell me what hardware I would need to run all these sensors together. Thanks :D.

Comment: Yes, easily....

Comment: @Majenko Are you sure? because it seems like the display is taking all of the pins, especially the power supply ones.  Also, it says that the fingerprint scanner needs a 12v power supply but as far as im aware arduino can only output 5v

Comment: No, the display only uses a tiny handful of the pins. It only plugs into the "Uno" footprint area pins and leaves all the rest blank. You can use power pins for more than one device at a time. If you need a higher voltage power supply then you have to get a higher voltage power supply. That has nothing at all to do with the Arduino.

Comment: @Majenko Okay thanks! So all of the other digital pins that come with the mega2560 can be configured to whatever output/input i need?

Comment: For simple IO, yes. For analogue there are more than 6 analog inputs. For serial communications there are more UART pins that aren't used, etc.

Comment: @Majenko Thank you so much!

Comment: if you run out, you can add a nano or pro mini using two serial pins, then have it talk to 1+ sensors.